# Bipartite Graph with fixed degree sequence Coloring Problem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A simple bipartite graph G has 20 vertices, of which 18 have degree 7, the others have degree 6. Find the chromatic number of the complement of G. 
I think that the two vertices with degree 6 must be in different color class and I guess the chromatic number is 10 but I haven't figure out a proof yet.

Answer (score 1):

For $i=6,7$ let $a_i$ [$b_i$] be a number of vertices of the graph $G$ belonging to a color class $A$ [$B$] with degree $i$. Then we have the following system.

$\cases{a_7+b_7=18\\
a_6+b_6=2\\ 
6a_6+7a_7=6b_6+7b_7}$

Since $a_6+b_6=2$ and $b_6-a_6$ is divisible by $7$, $a_6=b_6=1$. Then $a_7=b_7=9$. Therefore each color class of the graph $G$ has $10$ vertices.

Since complement $G^c$ of the graph $G$ consists of two cliques on each of color classes, $\chi(G^c)\ge 10$.

To show an upper bound for $\chi(G^c)$ we present the coloring of its vertices into $10$ colors constructed as follows. First we claim that the graph $G$ has a perfect mathching $M$. In order to show that we shall check that $G$ satisfies the conditions of [Hall’s Marriage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). Let $W$ be any non-empty subset of the set $A$. If $|W|\le 6$ then $|W|\le 6\le|N_G(v)|\le |N_G(W)|$ for any vertex $v\in W$. If 
$|W|\ge 5$ then $N_G(W)=B$, because any vertex $u\in B$ has degree at least $6$, so it is adjacent to some vertex in $W$. Now the coloring which puts to each pair of matched by $M$ vertices different color is the required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to solve this problem without using Hall's marriage theorem?

Comment: @sfe I'll think about it. But, anyway, any feasible coloring of vertices of $G^c$ in $10$ colors uses exactly $10$ colors in each class, so it generates a perfect matching in $G$ consisting of monochromatic pair. Therefore we still have to show the existence of a perfect matching.

Comment: @sfe Yes, we can inductively construct a perfect matching in $G$. Fix any its class $A$ and arbitrarily order its vertices $v_1,\dots, v_{10}$. At $i$-th step of the construction we shall try to find a neighbor of the vertex $v_i$ which is not yet matched with previous $v$’s. We can always did this for $i\le 6$. So if we’ll become stuck then $i\ge 7$ and all neighbors of  $v_i$ are already matched with previous $v$’s. Denote set of all these $v$’s as $V’$. Since $i\ge 7$, $|V’|\ge i-1=6$.

Comment: Pick any unmatched vertex $w$ from the class other than $A$. Since its degree is at most $6>4=10-|V’|$, it is adjacent with  some vertex $v’\in V’$. Now we can do the induction step by rematching $v’$ with $w$, and matching $v_i$ with the old match of $v’$.

Comment: Thanks! This algorithm works perfectly!